# ignore escape sequence c++

Tags: c++, string

I have tried searching google but could not find answer, can anyone tell that how to ignore escape character stored in string . I am using an array which holds different characters like this

```
string str[]={"| | / / ||","| |/ / ||", "| | ( \ \ \ \`_."}
```

Error message from compiler:

"unknown escape sequence" at

Comment: Escape the escape char: `"\"` --> `"\\"`

Comment: I didnt understand please explain further

Comment: ... and the '"' double quotes ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm assuming he wants to set up an array of 3 strings, so the double quotes do not need to be escaped.  If he wants the double quotes as part of his text, then he also needs to escape those.

Comment: @ZacHowland Having a closer look, yes ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @Zac has already pointed out, you can escape the `\` to avoid the problem. Another way you may find cleaner<sup>1</sup> would be to use raw string literals:

```
string str[]={R"(| | / / ||)",R"(| |/ / ||)", R"(| | ( \ \ \ \`_.)"};
```

Since it's not apparent from that sample, I'll point out one additional detail: if your strings might contain a `)` character, you can add more delimiters before the opening parenthesis, that also have to be matched next to the closing parenthesis, something like this:

```
string s = R"!(This (might be) an MS-DOS path\to\a\string)!";
```

Edit: Oh, one other minor detail: a raw string literal produces the same type of result as a normal string literal. You can intermix the two freely. For example, I could have left the first two literals above as normal literals, and only made the third one raw, since it's the only one that contains a backslash. For initializing an array (or other collections), I prefer to make them all raw if any of them is going to be, but that's strictly personal preference for the sake of consistency, not something the language requires.

---

<sup>1. Just in case: this is new with C++ 11, so if you're using an older compiler, this may not be supported.</sup>

Answer (score 6):

You must escape the `\` character.  Your string would look like this:

```
string str[]={"| | / / ||", "| |/ / ||", "| | ( \\ \\ \\ \\`_."};
```

In C++ (and most other C-based langauges), `\` is used to indicate an escape character (e.g. `\r`, `\n`, `\t`, etc).  If you want to have an actual "\" character in your string, you must escape it:  `\\`.